# Assertion Error Madness with Qt and Pickle

Tags: python, pyqt, pickle

I am getting an insane by its intensity and complexity Assertion Error on every Drag and Drop  (from one QListWidget onto another). I know the `AssertionError` is caused by one of class instance's attributes  (class instance variable is attached to QListWidget Item via .setData(). One of the attributes is not compatible with `pickle`. I would appreciate if you enlighten me on how to approach this problem and how to debug it efficiently. So far the only solution is to go through each class attribute one by one, setting it to None and then to check if that solved an `Assertion Error` problem. But such approach is extremely tedious and time consuming.

## EDITED LATER:

After hours of debugging I've shrink the code to its bare minimum. It closely replicates the same problem I have encountered when Qt widgets (such as QListWidget) are unable to use `pickle` to perform their tasks.

A Short info:

Two instances of ClassA and ClassB are declared. Then instB is stored in instA attribute. And vise versa: instA is stored to instB attribute. The rest is straightforward: instA via .setData() is assigned to ListWidget item. Drag'nDrop the item causes pickle to fail.
Please advise on how to avoid this situation in future. What causes it. And if there are possible scenarios to solve it.

[image]

---

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Base(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()

    def setInstB(self, instB):
        self['instB']=instB

class ClassA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__()  

class ClassB(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassB, self).__init__()

    def setInstA(self, instA):
        self.instA=instA

instA=ClassA()
instB=ClassB()

instA.setInstB(instB)
instB.setInstA(instA)


class Dialog(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, instA):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow,self).__init__()

        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(layout)       

        self.listA=QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.listA.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.listA.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.listA.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)


        listItem=QtGui.QListWidgetItem(str(id(instA) ) )
        listItem.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, instA)
        self.listA.addItem(listItem)

        self.listB=QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.listB.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.listB.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.listB.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

        layout.addWidget(self.listA)
        layout.addWidget(self.listB)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog=Dialog(instA)
dialog.show()
dialog.resize(480,320)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Newbie here... but do you have any dict that's inside a tuple?

Comment: Have you checked if your question isn't a duplicate of this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426981/python-pickle-dumps-assertionerror

Comment: I read the one you have mentioned. It's being said there that `There are some kinds of data the older pickle protocol cannot handle. To solve your problem, use pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`. It is unclear to me how to set 'use pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL' override with PyQt. Does anyone know?

Comment: The issue is behind QListWidget's drag'n'drop functionality that relies on `pickle` module to write/read data in and out. While the `.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` solution mentioned earlier might work in the situations where the code deals with `pickle` directly it is not clear how it could be implemented while working with Qt(PyQt) since all pickling happens by Qt/QListWidget. The `pickle` is not specific what exactly causes its confusion. It is hard to track the issue. I want to know if a solution that allows to avoid making a round trip or U-turn exists.

Comment: Could you provide some details on the class attached via `setData`? Is it a class you wrote or a Qt class? If it's your class, post the code please :)

Comment: The example code illustrating the problem is posted in 'Edited later' section of the original question. Let me know if you can crack it... if anyone can crack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googl'ing for `pyqt pickle protocol` reveals, there's an interface to set PyQt's pickle protocol:

```
QtCore.pyqtSetPickleProtocol()
QtCore.pyqtPickleProtocol()
```

See: http://freecode.com/projects/pyqt/releases/354104

So

```
QtCore.pyqtSetPickleProtocol(pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

might do the trick.

Comment: This could be a solution for me if it would not throw an `AttributeError: module object has no attribute pyqtSetPickleProtocol`. Could it be that PyQt is missing `.pyqtSetPickleProtocol()` method?

Comment: It works on my console. What version of PyQt are you using? According to those release notes, that function was introduced in 4.10.1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is the cyclic reference - `instA`references `instB` and vice versa.
The following works for me:

```
class Base(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()

    def setInstB(self, instB):
        self['instB']=instB

class ClassA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__()

class ClassB(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassB, self).__init__()

    def setInstA(self, instA):
        self.instA=instA

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import pickle

    instA=ClassA()
    instB=ClassB()

    instA.setInstB(instB)
    # omit the cyclic reference
    #instB.setInstA(instA)

    pickle.dumps(instA)
```

Commenting in `instB.setInstA(instA)` results in replicate of your error message.
So if you can live without the cyclic reference, this might be the easiest workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't abandon cyclic references from my code. I rely on them heavily. Do you think using `.pyqtSetPickleProtocol()` approach could be made working instead?